# C/Arduino switch case

Tags: c++, arduino, switch-statement

I'm writing code on Arduino (very similar to C, which I don't know, or very little), and I have a little issue concerning the switch/case statement.

I need my Arduino to do this or that depending on the values of a potentiometer (0 to 1023). However, I have no clue how to tell it case "0 to 200". For example, I tried

```
case 0..250:
  blablaSomeCode;
  break;
```

And so on... How can I do it?

I don't really want to write case 1 case 2 case 3...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to use a cascade of if's (also/especially if your value is a floating point number)

```
int value= ...; 

if (value>=0 && value<=250 {
    // some code 0..250
}
else 
if (value>250 && value<=500) {
    // some code 251..500
}
else 
if (value>500 && value<=1000) {
    // etc.
}
else {
    // all other values (less than zero or 1001...)
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! I actually wrote a function called isIn to verify it! but your code is a lot faster!

Comment: Glad to hear! If performance is an issue, you can reorder the ifs in a way that the most common cases are near the top.  (And please consider checking the answer as correct.)

Answer (score 5):

```
switch(val)
{
    case 0 ... 250:
        inRange(val);
        break;

    default:
        outOfRange();
        break;
}
```

While the code in the previous answer is valid, I would just stick with the switch statement as it is very applicable for the problem to solve.

Please note that using ranges ('...') is not conforming with the [ANSI C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C) standard, but it works fine in the Arduino environment.